# Why is building a wheel for <package> with a (PEP 517) indication so slow in an alpine Linux docker environment

Tags: python, docker, dockerfile, python-wheel

I'm installing numpy in an alpine Docker Python image, but it takes really very long when building the wheel at that point:

```
Building wheel for numpy (PEP 517) ... |
```

(the same appears for `pandas` e.g.)

What does this mean and why is it so slow?

I never faced a so slow install on Ubuntu, so I guess it may then be related to the alpine Linux environment.

Here is the Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9.1-alpine3.12

WORKDIR /app

RUN python -m pip install --upgrade pip \
  && pip install -U setuptools wheel \
  && pip install -U numpy
```

Host machine is an Ubuntu 18.04 mid-range laptop.

Answer (score 2):

not all docker images are born equal - each image packs s different set of packages.

that implies that it will take different effort to install required packages for running whatever you need (such as installing numpy)

you might like to [read this](https://pythonspeed.com/articles/base-image-python-docker-images/)

Comment: Nice link, I fall on some of these pages in between, this is highly interesting!

Comment: @s.k: hope i helped you :)